# Error with Quaternion.FromToRotation in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity

I get multiple errors whenever I run this code:

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation (Vector3(0, 0, 0), Vector3(0, 0, 270));
```

Can you suggest a fix for this code?

Errors:

- Expression denotes a `type', where a`variable', `value' or`method group' was expected
- The best overloaded method match for `UnityEngine.Quaternion.FromToRotation(UnityEngine.Vector3, UnityEngine.Vector3)' has some invalid arguments
- Argument `#1' cannot convert`object' expression to type `UnityEngine.Vector3'

Comment: Don't cross post to multiple SE sites. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33468238/error-with-quaternion-fromtorotation-in-unity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the `new` keyword when defining vectors.

Like so...

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation (new Vector3(0, 0, 0), new Vector3(0, 0, 270));
```

So you know, there is a predefined Vector3.zero which is equivalent to new Vector3(0,0,0), so you could also write your code like the following...

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation (Vector3.zero, new Vector3(0, 0, 270));
```

Note that there is no `new` keyword for Vector3.zero because you are not defining it, just using it.

Answer (score 0):

When using C# you need to use the *new* keyword in front of all constructors that you call (It's not the case with Javascript).

the correct syntax is

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation (new Vector3(0, 0, 0), new Vector3(0, 0, 270));
```